# NServiceBus test client not receiving Messages

Tags: nservicebus

I am very new to NService Bus, so I am trying to get it working with a simple test solution using LearningPersistence, obviously this will be changed soon!

So I have 3 projects:

**IceDataExtractor** - Client which sends a message

**IceProcessManager** - Processes messages

**Messages** - Contains a single Message class Messages

I am using the standard code generated by NServiceBus.Bootstrap.WindowsService 2.0.1

[Here is page I used as to get sample](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Bootstrap.WindowsService)

I then modified as follows

**Ice Data Extractor**

```
private async Task AsyncOnStart()
{
    try
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("IceDataExtractor");
        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
        transport.Routing().RouteToEndpoint(typeof(TestMessage), "IceProcessManager");
        endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        //TODO: optionally choose a different error queue. Perhaps on a remote machine
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        //TODO: optionally choose a different audit queue. Perhaps on a remote machine
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing
        endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
        endpointConfiguration.DefineCriticalErrorAction(OnCriticalError);
        //TODO: For production use select a durable persistence.
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/persistence/
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<LearningPersistence>();

        //TODO: For production use script the installation.
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

        endpointConfiguration.Conventions()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Messages") &&
                                     t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));

        endpoint = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        PerformStartupOperations();

        **var testMessage = new TestMessage {Id = Guid.NewGuid()};
        await endpoint.Send(testMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);**
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Fatal("Failed to start", exception);
        Environment.FailFast("Failed to start", exception);
    }
}
```

**Ice Process Manager**

```
private async Task AsyncOnStart()
{
    try
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("IceDataExtractor");
        var transport = **endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
        transport.Routing().RouteToEndpoint(typeof(TestMessage), "IceProcessManager");**
        endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        //TODO: optionally choose a different error queue. Perhaps on a remote machine
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        //TODO: optionally choose a different audit queue. Perhaps on a remote machine
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing
        endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
        endpointConfiguration.DefineCriticalErrorAction(OnCriticalError);
        //TODO: For production use select a durable persistence.
        // https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/persistence/
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<LearningPersistence>();

        //TODO: For production use script the installation.
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

        **endpointConfiguration.Conventions()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Messages") &&
                                     t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));**

        endpoint = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        PerformStartupOperations();

        var testMessage = new TestMessage {Id = Guid.NewGuid()};
        await endpoint.Send(testMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Fatal("Failed to start", exception);
        Environment.FailFast("Failed to start", exception);
    }
}
```

**TestMessage class**

```
using System;

namespace Messages.Commands
{
    public class TestMessage
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This all compiles and runs fine, other than performance warnings which I dont think matter

[image: Applications running fine]

I have a message handler

**TestMessageHandler**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Messages.Commands;
using NServiceBus;

namespace IceProcessManager
{
    public class TestMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<TestMessage>
    {
        public Task Handle(TestMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled TEst MEssage ID:{0}", message.Id);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the screenshot, no message is being received by the IceProcessManager.  What am I doing wrong?  I was thinking initially that I am sending the message too early, i.e. before the ProcessManager is up and running, but this not the problem because if I leave the ProcessManager running (i.e. run from explorer) then run the extractor, no message is receieved

Ideally I would like to have sent lots of messages to test this but I am not familiar with async stuff yet!

Can someone help please?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not missing something you are using the same endpoint name for both instances?

`var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("IceDataExtractor");`

While you are routing the message to "IceDataManager" which doesn't exist.

I guess you might have pasted the wrong code?

Comment: DOH!!!!! I guess it helps if I change code after copy paste!  That was it, although i was suprised to get more than 1 message when I changed this, maybe my messages were held in the queue?

Comment: You are correct, the messages would have been sent to the queue every time you started the endpoint previously.